# Restart workflow based on year change

Tags: 2013, workflow, designer-workflow, id

I have set a workflow to start automatically when a new item is added to the list (SharePoint 2013).

This workflow calculates an ID ("action" -> "set field in current item", field from source: "ID") so that there is an increasing number/index for each item is added.

This works fine.

However, my purpose is to restart the workflow (starting counting again from ID = 0) when the year changes.

How I could do that?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For that you have to store current year value some where else in different list(configurable).

- Query this list and get current year and compare it with today's date year if it is equal Increment ID to next counter.
- if not, Reset ID to 0 and update year column (in configuration list) to current date's year.

Comment: Thank you! Actually I checked that it's impossible to reset ID in a list so I found an other way

Comment: So when you say ID, you were referring to ootb Columns ID..it cannot be reset..please upvote and mark as answer if it was helpful